# Submitting to MySQL database from input of a single row in html table using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a html table that is created using AJAX and within that table I would like to submit some input values into a MySQL database, also using AJAX. The catch is that I need only the input from one row to be submitted.

The script below is what was used to generate the html table from the php server side php:

```
if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    $id = $_GET['query'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE sample_id=$id;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $input = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $input1 = $input['micro_analysis'];
    $order_id = $input['order_id'];
    $rows = explode(',', $input1);

    if (count($rows) > 0 ) {
        $output .= '<thead>
        <tr>
        <th>result_id</th>
        <th>m_analysis_id</th>
        <th>order_id</th>
        <th>sample_id</th>
        <th>Tests</th>
        <th>Detected</th>
        <th>Result</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th colspan="1"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';
        foreach ($rows as $row){
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row"; 
            $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
            $input2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
            $analysis = $input2['m_analysis'];


            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM results_database WHERE m_analysis_id=$row AND order_id=$order_id AND sample_id=$id"; 
            $result3 = mysqli_query($connect, $query3);
            $input3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
            $result_id = $input3['id'];
            $result = $input3['result'];

            $output .= 
            '<tr>

            <td><input name="result_id" id="result_id" value="'.$result_id.'" readonly></td>
            <td><input name="m_analysis_id" id="m_analysis_id" value="'.$row.'" readonly></td>
            <td><input name="order_id" id="order_id" value="'.$order_id.'" readonly></td>
            <td><input name="sample_id" id="sample_id" value="'.$id.'" readonly></td>


            <td>'.$analysis.'</td>
            <td><input name="detected" class="result_input" type="text" id="detected"></td>
            <td><input name="result" class="result_input" type="text" id="result" value="'.$result.'"></td>
            <td><input name="comment" class="result_input" type="text" id="comment"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>';
        }
        $output .= '</tbody>';
    }
    echo $output;
```

And here is the AJAX script to allow for the creation of the table:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.get_result').click(function (event) 
    { 
     event.preventDefault(); 

     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#tests').html(data);
    });
   });

  });
```

Up until this point the script works perfectly, but it is with the submission of inputs from this table that I get some wonky results. I would only submit the last row of inputs and would generate a whole lot of empty entries into the MySQL database. Also, instead of staying on the page, it redirects to a empty white page.

Here is the script for the form submission:

```
  function formSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../server/insert_tests.php',
      data: $('#frmBox').sterialize(),
      success: function(response){
        $('#success').html(response);

      }

    });
    var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
    return false;
  }
```

As well as the php script for database entries:

```
$result_id =test_input($_POST['result_id']);
$order_id = test_input($_POST['order_id']);
$sample_id = test_input($_POST['sample_id']);
$detected = test_input($_POST['detected']);
$result = test_input($_POST['result']);
$m_analysis_id = test_input($_POST['m_analysis_id']);

if ($result_id == '') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO results_database (order_id, sample_id, detected, result, m_analysis_id) VALUES ('$order_id', '$sample_id', '$detected', '$result', '$m_analysis_id');";
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE results_database SET order_id='$order_id', sample_id='$sample_id', detected='$detected', result='$result', m_analysis_id='$m_analysis_id' WHERE id='$result_id';";
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;


}
```

This is where the html table will be created within the html script:

```
 <h3 id="success"></h3>  

      <div class="result_input">
        <form action="../server/insert_tests.php" id="frmBox" method="post" onsubmit="return formSubmit();">
          <table id="tests">
          </table>          
        </form>        
      </div>
```

Anyone's expertise will be much appreciated, I think I need a `this` call somewhere in the AJAX script, but not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you have to change sterialize to serialize.

```
function formSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../server/insert_tests.php',
      data: $('#frmBox').sterialize(),
      success: function(response){
        $('#success').html(response);

      }

    });
    var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
    return false;
  }
```

to

```
function formSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../server/insert_tests.php',
      data: $('#frmBox').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
        $('#success').html(response);

      }

    });
    var form = document.getElementById('frmBox').reset();
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: That takes care of the white page redirection, but still creates lots of empty entries.

Comment: if you are inserting  data using ajax then why you are using action in your form attribute

Comment: please echo your insert query and then check